# internal 500 with no error_log data

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, whmcs

I am getting an internal 500 error which does not seem to write anything to the error_log for me to debug. In my access file I can see that I am connecting to the server but it responds with an internal 500.

My .htaccess file needs to do the following:

1. Rewrite to https://www. if there is no https request and it's not localhost
2. The rest is pretty straight forward and copied from the standard WHMCS .htaccess file

The error specifically happens with the #Products rules - It is also intermitted and appears to open the link if I open it via a hyperlink, but visiting the page directly from browser gives the error.

Any ideas?

```
 RewriteEngine On

 # Rewrite to HTTPS where needed / possible:
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

 # Products
 RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./pages.php?type=products&page=$1 [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^services/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./pages.php?type=services&page=$1 [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^legal/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./pages.php?type=legal&page=$1 [L,NC] 
 RewriteRule ^about/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./pages.php?type=about&page=$1 [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^debitorder$ ./debitorders.php [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^pp/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /modules/addons/propage/sites/$1 [L,NC]


 # Status:
 RewriteRule ^support/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./pages.php?type=support&page=$1 [L,NC]

 # Announcements
 RewriteRule ^announcements/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+\.html$ ./announcements.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^announcements$ ./announcements.php [L,NC]

 # Downloads
 RewriteRule ^downloads/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ ./downloads.php?action=displaycat&catid=$1 [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^downloads$ ./downloads.php [L,NC]

 # Knowledgebase
 RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+\.html$ ./knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=$1 [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ ./knowledgebase.php?action=displaycat&catid=$1 [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^knowledgebase$ ./knowledgebase.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: maybe you have "@" on your products php pages?

Comment: or something else, that turns off your error output.